# Access Angular module structure programmatically

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

Is there a way to access the Angular module structure programmatically? Maybe using reflection or by writing a build plugin?

In Maven you can write a plugin and access the structure using `project.dependencies` or `project.parent`. I'm basically looking for a way to do the same in Angular.

Any hints in the right direction are highly appreciated.

Comment: You might want to have a look at [Augury](https://github.com/rangle/augury) and [ngrev](https://github.com/mgechev/ngrev)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library [ngast](https://github.com/mgechev/ngast) was actually just was I was looking for. Thanks for the hint with [ngrev](https://github.com/mgechev/ngrev)

Comment: could you please let me know how you used it your project , same problem i also have, i have to call component dynamically and get all the html control and show it to 1 page

Comment: I used it to build a static code analysis. So I was interested in the structure at build time, not at runtime…